# How to write exists subquery DQL for many to many association

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql, doctrine-query

Given the entities below, would someone please help me understand how to write the DQL equivalent of the following SQL? I can't seem to find a good example of a DQL subquery that translates to a select on a pivot table. Thank you!

```
select *
from event a
where exists (
          select *
          from event_category b
          where b.event_id = a.id
            and b.category_id = 1
      )
```

Entities:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="event")
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @JoinTable(
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   name="event_category"
     * )
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
     */
    protected $categories;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @Id
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Doctrine Query Language](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

Your example could be written :

```
SELECT event FROM Event event
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT cat FROM Category cat 
    WHERE IDENTITY(cat.event) = event.id
    AND cat.id = 1
)
```

Now I might be wrong but I don't think you need a subquery here.

If you want events that have a given category :

```
SELECT event FROM Event event JOIN event.category WHERE category.id = 1
```